# JavaScript page reload timer with alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

What I am trying to do is after 59 minutes reload the page and after the page is reload display a message stating that the page has been reload. Then set the timer again and repeat the same thing. I am having trouble with hiding and displaying the alert and also a little lost on the logic after the first refresh.
This is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.Bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jQuery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script language="JavaScript"> <!--
function checkRefresh()
{
    if( document.refreshForm.visited.value == "" )
    {
        // This is a fresh page load
        document.refreshForm.visited.value = "1";
  document.getElementById(a).style.visibility="hidden";
    window.setTimeout(myalertfunction, 59 * 60 * 1000)
    }
    else
    {
document.getElementById(a).style.visibility="visible";
        // This is a page refresh
window.setTimeout(myalertfunction, 59 * 60 * 1000)
    }
} -->
</script>

</head>

<body onLoad="JavaScript:checkRefresh();">
<div class="alert alert-info fade in" id="a">
    <a href="#" "class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
    <strong>Info!</strong> This Page has been reloaded!
  </div>
<form name="refreshForm">
<input type="hidden" name="visited" value="" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="[seconds]">` to auto refresh the page

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<meta>` tag

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=http://www.example.com/test.html">
```

OR JavaScript's `setTimeout()`

```
setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.reload(1);
},60000)
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/auvhz5mp/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.Bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script language="JavaScript"> 
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var visitedValue = getParameterByName('visited',window.location.href);
    if (visitedValue === '1') {
      $('#a').show();
    }
    setTimeout(function(){

      $('#visited').val('1');
      $('#refreshForm').action = window.location.href;
      $('#refreshForm').submit();
    },3540000);
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="alert alert-info fade in" id="a" style="display:none;">
    <a href="#" "class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
    <strong>Info!</strong> This Page has been reloaded!
  </div>
<form name="refreshForm" id="refreshForm">
  <input type="hidden" id="visited" name="visited" value="" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did this work on your end because this doesn't work for me.

Comment: I tested the code on Internet Explorer and Firefox. The code works as follow : When the page opens for the first time, there is no message on the screen. After the time limit in setTimeout function, the form is submitted and the page is loaded again. Then, the message appears on the screen. I suggest you to try a shorter delay for the timeout. Something like 5000 (5 seconds).